# How to compute the area of this set in the plane?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, area

Let $f$ be a non-negative function which is defined, bounded, and integrable on a closed interval $[a,b]$, and let 
$$ S \colon= \{\ (x,y) \ | \ a \leq x \leq b, \ 0 \leq y < f(x) \ \}. $$
Then is the set $S$ measurable (i.e. can we assign an area to it)? And if so, then how to compute the area of $S$?

I am looking for an argument in terms of the notions of step functions and step regions.

Comment: This is the area of the undergraph of a function which is just 

$$\int_a^b f$$

Comment: The set $S$ in my original post is the difference of the ordinate set of $f$ over $[a,b]$ and the graph of $f$ over $[a,b]$. Now I know intuitively that the graph of $f$ has zero area. So, the area of the set $S$ must be equal to the area of the ordinate set of $f$, which is $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx$. But I would prefer a rigorous proof.

Comment: Proving the graph has measure $0$ does need to be done, but it's not difficult, you can do it directly for step functions then use density to extrapolate.

Answer (score 0):

Since  $f$  is a non-negative function defined, bounded, and integrable on the closed interval $[a,b]$, then the area of $S=\{(x,y) \mid x\in [a,b], y\in [0, f(x)]\}$ is the double integral:

$\begin{align}|S| & = \int_a^b \int_0^{f(x)}1 \;\mathrm{d}y\;\mathrm{d}x \\ & = \int_a^b [y]_{y=0}^{y=f(x)} \;\mathrm{d}x \\ & = \int_a^b f(x) \;\mathrm{d}x \end{align}$